# Google Cloud Memory Store (Redis) usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

1. I can be sure that my data will not be deleted for some reason, is it safe to use memory storage (Redis), or should I replicate data to the cloud data storage?
2. When I increase memory capacity all my data are safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The events that could cause data loss (i.e. a memory flush for some reason) in Memorystore, mostly only affect Memorystore "Basic" instances.

Memorystore has two instance tiers: [Basic and Standard](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-tiers).

Basic tier instaces are affected by the following events, which will cause a full cache flush:

- Instance scaling (i.e. upgrading or downgrading the instance capacity)
- Maintenance
- Instance restarts (triggered manually)

However, the Standard instance tier has a [High Availability configuration](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/high-availability), that includes a failover to replicate the data asynchronously. 
In Standard instances, in the case of any of the above events happens, the replica will be promoted to the main instance, and the memory will remain unaffected. However, the only data that might be lost are the writes that weren't propagated to the replica during the failover (due to the asynchronous nature of the replication). Nonetheless, the failover process is usually short and takes around 30 seconds to complete.

As well, you can [configure the behaviour of the instances](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/configuring-redis) when they reach maximum memory capacity, and use the `maxmemory-policy=noeviction` flag when configuring them, in order to avoid the instance to drop memory if this event happens. [See the official Redis documentation for more details](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache).

You mentioned replicating the data to Cloud Storage, but currently there is no way to replicate the data outside of Memorystore.

Regarding your second question, as I mentioned above, in a Standard tier instance, there won't be any data loss when changing the capacity of the instance.

**In short**: if you want the maximum possible data and instance uptime reliability, and avoid inconvenient memory flushes, Memorystore provides it when using Standard tier instances.

Comment: why i can connect to Memory Store (Redis) only from "App Engine Flexible Environment", why Google Engineers decided to not propagate it from "App Engine Standard Environment" ?

Comment: It's due to differences on the [environment where App Engine instances run](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments): is Standard, instances in a limited [sandbox environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)); while in Flexible they run in a Compute Engine VM instance, where they can connect to the rest of the resources and services on GCP. However, in App Engine Standard for Python3.X you can connect to the Memorystore API with the [Cloud Client libraries](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/redis/index.html).

Comment: maybe you have plans to do it also for "App Engine Java Standard Environment" as same as for Python3.X?

Comment: I believe that in the current Java runtimes in App Engine Standard, there are no plans to bring this libraries to being used there, as stated in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments), accessing general cloud platform products is a feature in the Flexible environment only. The Python3.X runtime is an exception to this rule, and currently it's only in beta. In the future it's possible that some new Java runtime in Standard will support access to general GCP resources, but at the moment, the best solution is to use the Flexible environment.

Answer (score 1):

One note about Standard tier instances, it is possible that a double failure can cause a full flush of the instance. We are working on enabling persistence and also will be providing a feature to import and export data to\from Memorystore instance.

The import\export feature is slated to be available early Q2.

Scaling behavior is outlined here. 
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/scaling-behavior

Product Manager
Cloud Memorystore